# Appending to text file then displaying only certain fields

Tags: java

I'm making a savings calculator using netbeans with a JFrameForm. below is my working code to save to a .txt. for some reason when I click save it will not append to a new line and wont save at all. I would like to then load certain rows to an array and display in my text area. eg the savings field. First code for the save button, second block for the load button.

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try{
       writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test.txt"));
       writer.write("\n" + date + "\t" + gross + "\t" + tax + "\t" + savings);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error saving");
    }finally{
        try{
            //close the writer
            writer.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error closing save"); 
        }
    }



try{
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        txaMain.read(br, null);
        br.close();


    }
    catch(Exception E){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error opening file");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for some reason when I click save it will not append to a new line and wont save at all
```

It is not saving because you are not flushing the character buffer stream that was grab from your write method.

**solution:**

`flush` it after you write from the text file

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test.txt"));
writer.write("\n" + date + "\t" + gross + "\t" + tax + "\t" + savings);
writer.flush();
```

Also if you want to append to the file while saving the text then add one more parameter in your `FileWriter` `FileWriter("C:\\test.txt, true")` **true** means to append the file when writing.

```
public FileWriter(String fileName,
                  boolean append)
```

Comment: for some reason it still overwrites the first save :/

Comment: @Mark.S see above edit.. add one more parameter in your FileWriter

Comment: You should also ensure that you are closing your resources, maybe with a `try-with-resources` block ;)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thank you! Works great. I'll do some research on loading a field back into an array. Felt bad enough asking this question which I'm sure has been asked a million times!

Comment: Also close all your stream after you used them as what @MadProgrammer just said using try-with-resources block